# Android Studio 3.0.1 Error: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly [SOLUÇÃO]

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Eu instalei o Android studio 3.0.1 e tentei criar o primeiro aplicativo com a escolha de uma atividade vazia, mas recebo a mensagem:

> A sincronização do projeto Gradle falhou. A funcionalidade básica (por exemplo, edição, depuração) não funcionará corretamente

e mensagem de erro como esta:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Required by:
>       project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
>   Already seen doctype.

[image]

[image]

e esta é a primeira parte da mensagem de log é:

> 2018-01-03 11:11:12,671 [d thread 8]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Already seen doctype.
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
>   2018-01-03 11:11:12,671 [d thread 8]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Already seen doctype.

Eu tentei alguma solução sugerida, como alterar a versão do gradle, atualizar o plugin do Kotlin (!) E assim, mas eles não funcionaram.

Qualquer solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tópico:
[Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096905/android-studio-3-0-1-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionality-e-g)

Estava com esse problema, depois de pesquisar, bastante encontrei a solução.

Para quem tiver esse problema no futuro tente fazer isso;

> File > Settings > Procure por: "Gradle";

[image: android-studio-3-0-1-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionality-e-g]

> Project level settings > Marque (x) Use local gradle distribution;
>
> Em "Gradle home" vocês baixem essa versão:
>   [Gradle 4.3.1](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/tag/v4.3.1)
>
> Crie uma pasta no c:/ com nome ".Gradle" e joguem os arquivos dentro dela.
>
> Voltando para "Gradle home" você seleciona o a pasta que você criou, caso apareça uma mensagem no log, baixem o que ele mandar.

É isso, espero que tenha ajudado vocês.